# How to get a post value in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, http-get

I need help with getting a Value posted from a form in VB.Net.

At the moment there is a form on a php website that is posting 2 values through to me.

```
name=Max
email=test"test.com
```

If i was using php i would use :

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Now the above fields are now captured within a variable.

How do i do the the same thing in VB.NET

Comment: How about using `controlName.Text`?  For eaxmple declare variable and assign the value of a control to it:  Dim myName as String   myName=ControlName,Text

Comment: I am assuming your controls are textboxes?

Comment: @ElenaDBA , no sorry i will update my question. Its actaully coming from a php form.

Comment: Are you using an ASP.NET application? If so, why don't you create a page to receive these values in 2 textboxes (can be hidden) and check in the TextBox Changed event the moment they receive the data? Or your application is a pure VB.NET Windows form app?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell if you are referring to Web text box's or PHP forms but I can help you with Web text box's..

Your question is unclear, but I will try my best.
Assuming you want to get a textbox's value into a variable. You would do like so:

Example Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ExampleTxtBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

If you want to assign the values on a certain command, for example, a button click. You would put this into the button click handles of the button.

Assuming you want to get the current text/value from the form's text box:

```
    Dim VariableOfTextBox As String 'Creates your Variable
    VariableOfTextBox = ExampleTxtBox.text 'Assigns the Value from your Text Box
```